# How to execute python script from postman?

Tags: python-2.7, postman

I have to execute a .py file (python file) saved on my local machine (say @C:\User\abc\dosomething.py) from postman from its pre-request section.
Essentially I need to call the .py file from javascript code but from postman only.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The Pre-request and test-scripts are executed in a sandbox environment.